# Prove that $(E[Y] - a)^2 \leq E[Y^2]P[Y > a].$

Tags: probability-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have problems trying to prove the following

Suppose  $Y$ is a positive r.v. such that $E[Y^2] < \infty$. If $0 \leq a < E[Y]$ ,
prove that
$$(E[Y] - a)^2 \leq E[Y^2]P[Y > a].$$

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
     (E[Y] - a)^2 &= (E[Y 1_{[Y\leq a]}]+E[Y 1_{[Y > a]}] - a)^2\\
     &\leq (a+E[Y 1_{[Y > a]}] - a)^2\\
     &=(E[Y 1_{[Y > a]}])^2\\
     &\leq E[Y^2]E[(1_{[Y > a]})^2]\\
     &= E[Y^2]E[1_{[Y > a]}]\\
     &= E[Y^2]P[Y > a].
\end{align*}

In the last inequality I used the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Is my proof right?

Comment: You probably should show how $0 \leq a \leq E[Y]$ implies the first inequality, but otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: It is completely correct. You should maybe clarify that due to the assumption the $E[Y]−a$ is positive, so if you upper bound it by some term you can use the fact that $(\cdot)^2$ is a increasing function.

Comment: Thanks!! that was a doubt that I had.